# How can I enable Pango so ImageMagick will see it under Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, linux-mint, pango

I'm running a Linux Mint installation that has ImageMagick installed and claims that libpango1.0-0 is installed, but ImageMagick can't see Pango:

```
$ convert -background transparent -fill black -pointsize 72 -size 800x pango:'<b>C.J.S. Hayward</p>' author.pngconvert: unable to open image `<b>C.J.S. Hayward</p>': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PANGO' @ 
error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `author.png' @ 
error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

`author.png` is the intended output file; it shouldn't exist yet.

A brief search turned up, among other results, a suggestion to go behind the package manager's back and recompile ImageMagick from scratch with `--with-pango`. But I'll be surprised if that's the best available solution.

What should I be doing so ImageMagick sees Pango?

**--UPDATE--**

`identify -version` gives:

```
$ identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 
http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

This is after making sure `libpango1.0-dev` and `libpangocairo-1.0.0` were installed.

**--FURTHER UPDATE--**

I decided to install from source and see what would happen. 
[From `/usr/local`:]

```
./bin/convert convert -background transparent -fill black -pointsize 72 -size 800x pango:'<b>C.J.S. Hayward</p>' author.png
```

./bin/convert: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I get this same error message when I try to run `./bin/identify -version` and `convert -list configure` from the new version.

One additional piece of diagnostic information: I get the errors as described from my Linux Mint laptop, which I have been using as a development box. After compiling from source created breakage, I tried running the following command from my Debian webserver:

```
convert -background transparent -fill black -pointsize 72 -size 800x -gravity center pango:'<b><span size="49152">C.J.S. Hayward</span></b>' author.png
```

I don't absolutely need to have Pango supported on my development box. However, it irks me that I have so much trouble getting this working on a mainstream Linux distribution.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please share which version of Linux Mint you are using? (For example, the output of the command "inxi -S' with a capital S would be jolly useful.)

Comment: Thank you! System:    Host: _____ Kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6  Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

Comment: OK .. and the result of 'identify -version' please?

Comment: Do you have libpangocairo-1.0.0 installed?

Comment: Ensure `libpango1.0-dev` is installed. The C-header files are what  is missing.

Comment: @emcconville Thank you; see the revised question for further information.

Comment: Check to see that pango was actually installed. Type: `convert -list configure`. Then check the line for CONFIGURE and for DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS. Do either show `--with-pango=no` or `--without-pango`. If so, you must remove `--without-pango` from your ./configuration file. Perhaps the distro came with it disabled. One other thought is that your tango is too old. My current pango is @1.40.11_0

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks; the CONFIGURE option does not mention Pango. DELEGATES include Pango. That is the only place "pango" appears in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your ImageMagick command as:

`convert -background transparent -fill black -pointsize 72 -size 800x pango:'<b>C.J.S. Hayward</p>' author.png`

`But if you look carefully, you start your text with <b> (bold), but end it with </p> (closing paragraph). Try changing </p> to </b>`

Does that work? If not, try using double quotes. If that does not work, then, I suspect your IM compile is configured as: --without-pango--

I tried you command in IM 6.8.9.9 with pango enabled and using pango @1.40.11_0 and it works fine.

Comment: I have upvoted this appreciated answer, but I think I posted with two problems: the close paragraph tag, and another problem not successfully diagnosed yet. I found and fixed the tag error, but the problems do not appear to change once that is corrected. **Conjecture:** I believe that the other problem besides my bad Pango string is upwind of my wrong Pango usage, and things halted before the point that a malformed Pango string would be evaluated to cause a crash. Thanks,